# How can htop be used to suspend a process and all its child processes?

Tags: process-management, htop

I use `recoll` to index files and it kicks in a inopportune times.

When I use `htop` to change the view to a tree view using F5 and filter the process list I see a master process running and child processes underneath it. When I press F9 to choose a termination option it doesn't seem to respond to the `SIGTERM` option so I have to use the `SIGKILL` option.

Is there an option to pause or stop the parent process and all its children rather than kill it outright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Space</kbd> to tag a process. The kill command applies to all tagged processes.

There's no easy way to tag a process and its children, but the tree view (<kbd>t</kbd>) should list them contiguously.

Depending on how recoll is run, the processes may be in their own [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). If they are, then you can use `kill -STOP -1234` to suspend them all, where 1234 is the process group ID (usually but not necessarily the process ID of the initial process in the group). You can check with `ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,comm -C recoll`, then `ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,comm ww | grep -v recoll` to see if there are any other processes in the process group. Htop doesn't have an interface to process groups.

If all the processes are called `recoll`, then an easier method is to filter the processes by name. In htop, use the filter command, then you can easily tag the processes you want to kill. On the command line, run `ps $(pgrep recoll)` to list the matching processes. If you're happy with the list, run `pkill -STOP recoll` to suspend those processes.

Comment: The  indexer has one main process named recollindex and possibly many subprocesses in their own process group, each running a different command and which may themselves execute other commands. So I guess that none of the above will work. My suggestion, not directly addressing the question, would be to either run recollindex in batch mode (with cron), or outright kill it (SIGTERM) when you want it to stop. It is designed to exit gracefully, which may take a few seconds. Then maybe have a periodic cron to restart it in case you forget (recollindex guards against multiple instances).

Answer (score 6):

[Since version `2.0.0`](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/commit/3383d8e5561dfc6fb2b65e0a194df94ccb5e08af) ([released in 2016](https://hisham.hm/htop/releases/)), you can press `c` to tag the process and its children. This is mentioned in the built-in help which is shown on `h`.

Then you can press `k` to send a signal to the tagged processes; you'll be presented with the list of all possible signals to choose from.

Answer (score 4):

You can choose to send the signal `SIGTSTP` or `SIGSTOP`:

- `SIGTSTP` : Is the signal sent when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. It will suspend and stop the process, you can resume it using `bg` (resumes it in the background) or `fg` (resumes it bringing it back to the foreground).
- `SIGSTOP`: Simply stops the process. Can't be ignored can't be blocked. The process will only resume if you send it a `SIGCONT` signal.

Comment: The question is more about stopping or pausing the tree of processes in one go

Comment: @vfclists I don't think that's possible without changing how the job/process behaves to the received signals.

Comment: @M.Becerra is possible _resume_ a _suspended/stopped_ process (`SIGSTOP`) through either `fg` or `bg` too - I just tested.